# Problem with Numba jit: "Typing error" and "All templates rejected with/without literals"

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error, typeerror, numba

I am implementing a program that solves a differential equation in Python 3.7.3 and there is one function that I just can't get to compile with Numba. The most recent version of it is:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, uint16, complex128, prange

# Here is the setup of the program, as well as variable initialization

@jit((complex128[:, :, :], uint16, complex128[:, :], complex128[:, :], complex128[:, :]), nopython=True)
def upd_x(rhs: np.ndarray, m: int, s: np.ndarray, a: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    x = np.zeros((3, m, m//2+1))
    x[2] = s*(1-a*(rhs[0]+rhs[1]))
    for i in range(2):
        x[i] = a*(rhs[i]+b*x[2])
    return x
```

What it is supposed to do is, take the "right hand side" (`rhs`) of the equation and update `x` (`x` has 3 components which are real fields, and the code is "updating" it in Fourier space, that is why the last axis is `m//2+1` instead of `m`) with Schur's complement method. When I ran the code I got the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Username/Desktop/Program/Program.py", line 95, in <module>
    @jit((complex128[:, :, :], uint16, complex128[:, :], complex128[:, :], complex128[:, :]), nopython=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\numba\decorators.py", line 186, in wrapper
    disp.compile(sig)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler_lock.py", line 32, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py", line 659, in compile
    cres = self._compiler.compile(args, return_type)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py", line 83, in compile
    pipeline_class=self.pipeline_class)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 955, in compile_extra
    return pipeline.compile_extra(func)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 377, in compile_extra
    return self._compile_bytecode()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 886, in _compile_bytecode
    return self._compile_core()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 873, in _compile_core
    res = pm.run(self.status)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler_lock.py", line 32, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 254, in run
    raise patched_exception
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 245, in run
    stage()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 501, in stage_nopython_frontend
    self.locals)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 1105, in type_inference_stage
    infer.propagate()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\numba\typeinfer.py", line 915, in propagate
    raise errors[0]
numba.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Invalid use of Function(<built-in function setitem>) with argument(s) of type(s): (array(float64, 3d, C), Literal[int](2), array(complex128, 2d, C))
 * parameterized
In definition 0:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 1:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 2:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 3:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 4:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 5:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 6:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 7:
    All templates rejected without literals.
This error is usually caused by passing an argument of a type that is unsupported by the named function.
[1] During: typing of staticsetitem at C:/Users/User/Desktop/Program/Program.py (98)

File "Programa.py", line 98:
def upd_x(rhs, m, s, a, b):
    <source elided>
    x = np.zeros((3, m, m//2+1))
    x[2] = s*(1-a*(rhs[0]+rhs[1]))
    ^
```

I don't understand why the error message suggests that the variable type is unsupported, and I also don't know what is wrong that I need to correct. The versions that I am using are numba==0.44.1, numpy==1.16.1.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you remove "nopython" option and give it a try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Numba was unable to determine what the type of the output `x`, is, so I added a `dtype` to `x`. Then you run into mixing `np.int64` and `uint16`, in size arguments to `np.zeros` since `3` is interpreted as a `i64`. So the following will compile:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, uint16, complex128, prange

# Here is the setup of the program, as well as variable initialization

@jit(complex128[:,:,:](complex128[:, :, :], uint16, complex128[:, :], complex128[:, :], complex128[:, :]), nopython=True)
def upd_x(rhs: np.ndarray, m: int, s: np.ndarray, a: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    mx = np.int64(m)
    x = np.zeros((3, mx, mx//2+1), dtype=np.complex128)
    x[2] = s*(1-a*(rhs[0]+rhs[1]))
    for i in range(2):
        x[i] = a*(rhs[i]+b*x[2])
    return x
```

Also, note that I added a return type to the signature being passed to `@jit`although this isn't necessary, I believe.

And so I use the inputs:

```
m = 4
x = np.zeros((3, m, m//2+1), dtype=np.complex128) + 2 + 2j
y = np.zeros((m, m//2 + 1 ), dtype=np.complex128) + 1 + 1j

upd_x(x, np.uint16(m), y, y, y)
```

and this gives back something sensible, I think.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, I have tried to implement the solution you suggest but I still get the same error message as before. Do you think it would be necessary for me to show how all the variables are defined to see if any of those is causing problems?

Comment: Just added an example call.

Comment: I have tried the example you gave and it does work in my PC, so I will fix my program based on this. Thank you.